# Use NANT to sign a .pfx

Tags: teamcity, nant, pfx

I am trying to sign a .pfx file using NANT in my TeamCity build. the following just show the help information for sn.exe. What am I missing

```
<exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe"  
   verbose="false">
  <arg value="sn -i ${rootFolder}\ApplicationFolder\MYKey.pfx" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that exec command is not correctly formed. It should look like this:

`<exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe" verbose="false">
  <arg value="-i"/>
  <arg value="${rootFolder}\ApplicationFolder\MYKey.pfx" />
</exec>`

You can also look at [examples here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/exec.html) as reference